# TypeError: http.createServer is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install Node on AWS and after installing, I am using `http.createServer` which is giving me the following error.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
     ^

TypeError: http.createServer is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/test1/test1.js:4:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Here is the code I am typing in my test1.js

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 9000;

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello there, world\n');
}).listen(port);

console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me. Which node version are you using? Did you install http module?

Comment: @RémiC. `http` is default in nodejs

Comment: node -v
v8.11.1

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal you're right, my bad. I have the same node version, so it's not that...

Comment: I launched it via my IDE, how do you launch it ? If I do the command line I get an exception with the port so I changed it to 8080 and it worked fine, can you try that?

Comment: I am launching via terminal with node test1.js

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-t-make-it-to-work-with-the-hello-js?answer=29915 check this @MarkusHayner

Comment: @MarkusHayner do you have the same error with the port 8080?

Comment: same error even if I change to 8080